# How to map in Realm List an array of integers from JSON with ObjectMapper

Tags: swift, realm, objectmapper, realm-list

I have JSON:

```
{ 
"id": 5,
"name": "Name of object",
"filter_ids": [ 10, 15, 20 ] 
}
```

I use [ObjectMapper](https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/ObjectMapper) for parse JSON to Realm Object.

I have vars in object:

```
dynamic var identifier: Int = 0 
dynamic var name: String = "" 
var filter_ids = List<Int>()
```

How to map filter_ids var?

```
func mapping(map: Map)  {
     identifier <- map["id"]
     name <- map["name"]
     filter_ids <- map["filter_ids"] //?????? not work
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your issue, but there's no need to use a 3rd party framework for parsing JSON, you can simply use Swift 4's `Decodable` protocol.

Answer (score 0):

I used cocoaPod (carthage works too) [ObjectMapperAdditions](https://github.com/APUtils/ObjectMapperAdditions)

```
filter_ids <- (map["filter_ids"], RealmTypeCastTransform())
```

It works for Int, String, Bool arrays.

[Duplicated discussion](https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/ObjectMapper/issues/919)